# Interval Partitioning In Oracle on SYSDATE

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, dynamic-sql, database-partitioning

I am looking for the best way to create partitions dynamically. Like, partition 1 would hold all records dated as of today(SYSDATE), and partition 2 would hold records of yesterday's date(SYSDATE-1) and so on till SYSDATE-29.

So far I have tried using:

```sql
PARTITION BY RANGE(COLUMN_NAME)
INTERVAL(NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'DAY'))
(
PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (select SYSDATE from dual)
);
```

and

```sql
PARTITION BY RANGE(COLUMN_NAME)
INTERVAL(NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'DAY'))
(
PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (to_char(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YY')from dual)
);
```

But I'm getting an error as follows:

> "ORA-14019: partition bound element must be one of: string, datetime or interval literal, number, or MAXVALUE"

So, how  would I be able to do this?

Comment: You cannot use SYSDATE in partition <...> less than clause. It must be a literal as given in the error or MAXVALUE key word.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of an interval-partitioned table:

```
create table partition_interval_demo
( id         number(6)     generated always as identity
, val        varchar2(50)  not null
, sale_date  date          not null )
partition by range (sale_date) interval (interval '1' day)
( partition p1 values less than (date '0001-01-01') );
```

Check where your definition is different.

Answer (score 0):

```
column curr_date new_value current_date
select to_char(sysdate, 'MM-DD-YYYY') crr_date
  from global_name
/

create table partition_interval_demo
( id         number(6)     generated always as identity
, val        varchar2(50)  not null
, sale_date  date          not null )
PARTITION BY RANGE(sale_date) INTERVAL(NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'DAY'))
(
PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('&current_date', 'MM-DD-YYYY'))
);
```